# Will our Oauth Consent Screen have to go through verification again when adding contacts.other.readonly?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

Our Google Oauth Consent Screen is currently verified and includes the

**https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts** scope.

We are now migrating to the People API and we want to have access to the

**https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly** scope.

If we add that to our Oauth Consent Screen, will that trigger a re-verification step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-verification of the OAuth Consent Screen is required when adding sensitive scopes to the GCP Project. Both of these are sensitive scopes.

Referring to this [Support Article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en):

**Sensitive scopes**

Some of the scopes used by the following APIs are considered sensitive; see the API documentation or look for the lock icon in the Cloud Console. If your app requests sensitive scopes, and doesn't meet any of the criteria for an exception (see below), you will need to verify that your app follows the API Services User Data Policy.

For a complete list of Google APIs, see [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#people). To check if scopes are sensitive or restricted, add the scopes to your project via the [Google Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com/).

Addendum: Note that in [People API](https://developers.google.com/people) the two scopes you are defining allow access to separate lists:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts - [Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) list
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly - [Other Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/other) list

[image]

It's preferable to add both scopes.

Comment: Yes, That's the documentation for this.  However this doesn't help because https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly  is arguably a subset of what https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts  authorizes (or at least used to authorize before the force migration to the people api).

So, my question is... will adding "contacts.other.readonly" to an Oauth Screen that previously went through verification for "contacts" trigger another verification?

Comment: In [People API](https://developers.google.com/people) the two scopes allow access to different lists so one is not a subset of the other.

Comment: Thank you.  In the Contacts API, I don't think that was the case.  With the Contacts API, if you authorized using the "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" scope, you would gain access to all contacts (including Other Contacts).  That is the scope we were using with our Oauth Consent screen (which, yes was verified for /auth/contacts but we were told that covered /m8/feeds scope).    So, now that we are migrating to the People API, it seems we have to add contacts.other.readonly to gain access to what we had before?

Comment: Yes that is correct.